# Delphi - Creating MySQL database at runtime

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, runtime

I have a delphi application which connects to MySQL database, however, I would like to give create an easy way for my end user to implement the MySQL database. I thought about creating a button within my application which the user could press to delete any current instances of the scehma, and create a new schema with the correct tables and columns which my application requires to function.

I have written the code to create the new database. It is as follows:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fakeschema;   
USE fakeschema;  
CREATE TABLE table1  
(IDtable1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Line1 varchar(45),  
Line2 varchar(45));
```

The code functions correctly within MySQL, however I am receiving an SQL Syntax error when executing the code. I am getting of:

> > error in your SQL syntax near 'USE fakeschema; CREATE TABLE table1 (IDtable1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY NO'

I am using an `ADOConnection` to link to the datasource. I am writing the connection string once the button has been pressed. I am using an `ADOQuery` to execute the SQL code.

Here is a snippet of the code which I am using to connect to the database:

```
ADOC.ConnectionString := 'PROVIDER = MSDASQL; DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};
SERVER=localhost; Data Source=faketest; DATABASE=fakeschema; USER ID=root;
PASSWORD=pass; OPTION=3;';
ADOC.DefaultDatabase := 'fakeschema';  
ADOC.Connected := True;
```

Am I using the wrong tools/methods? I am new to MySQL and I am currently learning Delphi.

Comment: "I am receiving an SQL Syntax error" without posting the specific error message you're receiving is meaningless. Please [edit] your question and include the **exact** error message. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite I have made the edit. Thanks

Comment: @KenWhite I see what you mean. I've had a lot of trouble in the past, and all i've needed to do was edit a few chars. However, that doesn't seem to be the case here. I tried removing auto_inc and notnull, and I tried starting the column bracket from the `line1` part, so that the id line was completely removed... nut no luck. Both provide the exact same error, just with the corresponding lines of code showing.

Comment: do you need to use a different component than a TAdoQuery?  It may only want a single statement executed at a time.  I know with Interbase/Firebird style you would need to use a TIBScript component to execute multiple statements "at once". But I don't know. Just a guess

Comment: Disregard my last comment. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/create-table.html) isn't really clear on what's required here. I'm still digging around. :-)

Comment: @Jason I had a search around and found this article: http://delphionderdils.com/2012/01/28/how-to-create-mysql-database-runtime-in-delphi.pas  
It uses a different component (which I do not have installed) and executes one line of code at a time. Maybe I need to do something like this?

Comment: Possibly.  But I think the issue is with having, say, "use fakeschema" AND your "create table..." in the same SQL component.  if you removed the use fakeschema line - i would create one TADOQuery to create the database alone, then create a second one with just the create table statement (no use fakeschema as you will setup the default schema when you connect to the database).  So, execute the Create Database query.  Then connect to your database using your above connection string.  Then execute the 2nd query with just the create table statement in it

Comment: copy and pasting your create table as is above by itself worked fine for me - but I was testing on MySQL 5.1.  R u really using 3.x version?

Comment: Are you connecting your Query component to a database that does not exist? How can you connect to fakeschema if you haven't created it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in one of my comments, the issue is trying to execute multiple *individual* SQL statements in a single TAdoQuery component.

In an ideal world, you would have a component such as MyDAC which has a script component you could use in place of the TAdoQuery (MyDAC would give you other benefits too such as not having to connect via ODBC).  I don't know if there any free MySQL components out there which have a scripting component.

Another approach is you could create a script file (eg createFakeSchema.sql) and execute it through the command line.  eg:

createFakeSchema.sql:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fakeschema;   
USE fakeschema;  
CREATE TABLE table1  
(IDtable1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Line1 varchar(45),  
Line2 varchar(45));
```

and example source code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.DoExecuteScriptFile;
var
  cmd: string;
  KeepOpen: Boolean;
begin
  KeepOpen := True;

  // option to automatically close window once execution is done
  // for releasing you would not want it kept open, but handy for debugging
  if KeepOpen then
    cmd := '/k '
  else
    cmd := '/c ';

  cmd := cmd + Format(' mysql -uroot -proot -D%s < "%s"', ['FakeSchema', 'createFakeSchema.sql']);
  ShellExecute(handle,'open', 'cmd.exe', Pchar(cmd), nil, SW_SHOW );
end;
```

This way you can create your script file externally somewhere, test it through MySQL yourself then when you know your *script* is working, you can run it through your program.  If you want to hide the command window while executing change the SW_SHOW in ShellExecute to SW_HIDE.  This way you don't even need any components at all - just have mysql.exe accessible in the path or include the full path in the cmd statement.

This was done in MySQL 5.1, so hopefully works for 3.5...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've split the Queries up and created a separate query for creating the database. I have one which simply creates the database `fakeschema` and then I have a separate `ADOQuery` which adds SQL to `CREATE table1`, executes the SQL, clears the Query and then adds and executes the SQL for the next table etc. It works fine. I like the idea of executing from a fiile, and may use that for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/create-table.html) for MySQL 3.x, and scroll waaay down the page on `CREATE TABLE`, you'll see an example in one of the comment posts of what appears to be the proper syntax. It appears to be more like this (untested, of course):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1 (
  IDtable1 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  Line1 varchar(45),  
  Line2 varchar(45)
  PRIMARY KEY (IDTable1)
);
```

Here's another example I found at [DevArticles](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Using-Delphi-with-MySQL/2/)

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `aID` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `auth` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `article_body` text NOT NULL,
  `date_published` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`aID`)
)
```

You might want to reconsider your strategy, though. If the user accidentally clicks the `Reset Database` button and deletes *all of their data*, this may cause you some issues (possibly legal ones, depending on where you live and what data is involved). :-)

It might be better to think of backing up the data and then do a `TRUNCATE` of the tables instead, where you could restore from the backup if something went wrong. This would allow re-use of the existing schema.

Comment: I don't think his Create Table statement is the issue - worked fine for me on ver 5.1 - but there may be differences in older versions.  I think the issue is trying to execute multiple statements in a single TADOQuery component

Comment: @Jason: If that's the case, a quick change to a `TADOCommand` component might fix it, because I've executed multiple statements there using SQL Server. As I said, I can't test either way, because I don't have MySQL installed currently. The docs for MySQL 3.x seem to indicate that the syntax is wrong, but I didn't look at 5.1 because the poster said 3.51 in the connection string (5.1 docs aren't relevant then). :-) With TSQL, you have to omit the `GO` (it's only used by SSMS), but the poster's syntax works fine with datatype corrections.

Comment: Quite possible.  FWIW, I set a TAdoCommand.CommandText to the initial SQL (minus the create database line) and calling Execute gave the exact error the OP received.  Removing the use fakeschema line from the TAdoCommand.CommandText worked correctly, so I'm still tending towards multiple statements in a single TAdoQuery :).

Comment: @Jason: You should write an example (with code) and post an answer, then. :-)

Comment: I know my way of creating tables is a bit silly as the user has the option to completely drop all previous data. It's also not very easy for a user with basic knowledge to install MySQL and create a schema, so that my program can create the tables. However, I have hard coded the names of tables and schemas into queries within my code, therefore I have to use the exact same table names within MySQL. For future reference, what would be a good way of having an option where the user can create the table names and database name within my app and then create said tables and use them in queries?

Comment: My comment wasn't about being "silly". It's about risk (both to you and your customers) when you give them a way to "delete everything" that can be accidentally executed. I've known of companies that were sued when a customer used a feature of their software that was designed to reset data, because the customer claimed it was "not documented properly, and they lost $$$ of financial data". As far as the "user creating table and database name...and use them in queries", that's far too large a question to answer here in comments, but you could post it as a new question. (I'd be more specific.)

Comment: @KenWhite Fair enough. I appreciate what you're saying. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever receive a MySQL error message like

> error in your SQL syntax **near** '*(quoted)*'

you always have to look at the code that is **before** that *quoted* part.

In this special case `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fakeschema;`

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html) is also very clear about that

> CREATE SCHEMA is a synonym for CREATE DATABASE as of MySQL **5.0.2**.

So you cannot use this *synonym*, because your MySQL server (version below 5.0.2) or in this case the ODBC driver did not know this.

This should get rid of the **current** error message

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS fakeschema;   
USE fakeschema;  
CREATE TABLE table1(
  IDtable1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  Line1    varchar(45),  
  Line2    varchar(45)
);
```

Comment: The problem still exists even if you remove the create database statement because the OP was trying to execute the three statements in a single TAdoQuery - as is my understanding.  Certainly the CREATE SCHEMA statement cannot be used as pointed out by you now, but I believe he will still run into the same issue (I do on Delphi 7 and MySQL 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

A solution (based on @Jason 's) that does not involves cmd.exe is to use mysql *source* command:

```
cmd := '-u USER_NAME -pUSER_PASSWORD DB_NAME -e "source createFakeSchema.sql"';
ShellExecute(handle, 'open', 'mysql.exe', Pchar(cmd), 'PATH_TO_MYSQL', SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a hard job to find how to create a database. I'm using "Zeos":

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ShellAPI, ZAbstractConnection, ZConnection, DB,
  ZAbstractRODataset, ZAbstractDataset, ZDataset;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    ZConnection1: TZConnection;
    ZQuery: TZQuery;
    btn2: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ZConnection1.Protocol := 'mysql-5';
  ZConnection1.Database := '';
  ZConnection1.User := 'root';
  ZConnection1.Password := 'root';
  ZConnection1.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vSQL : string;
begin
  ZQuery.Close;
  ZQuery.SQL.Clear;
  vSQL := 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`';
  ZQuery.SQL.Add(vSQL);
  ZQuery.ExecSQL;
end;

end.
```

I hope that I can help anyone;

Best Regards