# work with mysql-commande line with delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

Hi guys I'm working on a big project for the first time; I want to create an intelligent program but I have some big problem in this code.

```
program base;
{$mode delphi}
uses
crt,
Windows,   // for constant SW_NORMAL
ShellApi;  // for function ShellExecute
 var
  comand,nomdb:widestring;
 procedure createdatabase(var comand,nomdb:widestring);

 begin

 writeln('Put the name of database');
 readln(nomdb);
 comand:='C:\AppServ\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe -uroot -ptest1234 -e "create database hello ;"';
 ShellExecute(0, 'open', PWideChar(comand), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);

 end;



 begin
  createdatabase(comand,nomdb);
 end.
```

I can't create the database when I run my code and when I type in the cmd this command

> C:\AppServ\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe -uroot -ptest1234 -e "create database
>   hello ;"

I can then create the DB so I guess I have a problem with my code but I don't know where that is!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi - Creating MySQL database at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048092/delphi-creating-mysql-database-at-runtime)

Comment: i'm new in delphi and it same for me hard how can i modify my code to run with no error

Comment: @MiralAmineKhadhraoui What is the actual problem you are having with it? Are you getting a compile-time error?  A runtime error? There is no error checking in your code. You say you can't create the database, but you didn't say WHY. In any case, have a look at [the reply I just now posted to your same question on the Lazarus forum](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,42821.msg299128.html#msg299128). You really should be using `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the executable file path and the parameters separately:

```
command:= 'C:\AppServ\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe';
parameters:= '-uroot -ptest1234 -e "create database hello ;"';
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PWideChar(command), PWideChar(parameters), nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

You will hit a different problem with that: `ShellExecute` will return immediately and not wait until the command has actually finished to create the database. If you want that, use `CreateProcess` instead of `Shellexecute` as explained in [How can I wait until an external process has completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336227/how-can-i-wait-until-an-external-process-has-completed)